# Can you shift an images' rect center?

Tags: python, pygame, collision, rect

My image's rectangle is just to the right of the image and I want to move the rect left by a few pixels or move the image right. Additionally is there a way of moving the rect down or making the top smaller whilst the bottom of the rect stays the same?

```
PLAYER_RECT_HIT = py.Rect(0, 0, 33, 33)
class Player(py.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, game, x, y):
        self._layer = PLAYER_LAYER
        self.groups = game.all_sprites
        py.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, self.groups)
        self.game = game
        self.running = False
        self.jumping = False
        self.wallSlide = False
        self.current_frame = 0
        self.last_update = 0
        self.load_images()
        self.image = self.idle_frames[0]
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (x, y)
        self.hit_rect = PLAYER_RECT_HIT
        self.hit_rect.center = self.rect.center
        self.pos = vec(x, y)
        self.vel = vec(0, 0)
        self.acc = vec(0, 0)
```

Here's an example, the red box is my rect, I want to shift it to the left so as to make my image touch the rectangle of the box which is in blue

[image]

Comment: *My image's rectangle is just to the right of the image* What does that actually mean? You call `self.rect = self.image.get_rect()` so the rect is exactly the size of the image.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make the top of the rect smaller while the bottom stays in the same place, you can do this:

```
newRect = pygame.Rect(
    oldRect.top - 10, 
    oldRect.left, 
    oldRect.width - 10, 
    oldRect.height
)
```

Hope this helps!